# localhost Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: cors

My local web app serving at `localhost:3000` wants to access resources accessible at `localhost:8080/files` (in some directory `.../www/files` that Apache reads).

To get around the CORS constraint, I tried adding a `.../www/files/.htaccess` with this content :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

But it still does not work ("No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource").

What am I missing ?

N.B. Disabling CORS in the browser works, but is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
First, .htaccess files are unnecessary and not recommended if one can edit his Apache conf.
Secondly, I was missing a header "Range" in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers directive. Adding it to the list solved the problem.